# ftp_get not working, no error

Tags: php, filezilla

if I get file from root it works, but if I want to get file from folder it fails but shows "file downloaded successfully".

here is code

```
$sourcefile = "test.doc";
$local_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sites/default/files/" . "answerdoc" . $node->nid . $sourcefile; 
$remote_file = "test.doc";
$currPath = "documents";        


if (@ftp_login($conn_id, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)) {

    // it works
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);               

    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file , $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('file downloaded successfully'));
    } else {
        drupal_set_message(t('there was error'));
    }


    if(@ftp_chdir($conn_id,$currPath)){

        $answerdir ="Answer";
        // it does not work but shows "file downloaded successfully"
        if(@ftp_chdir($conn_id,$answerdir)) {   

            ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

            if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
                drupal_set_message(t('file downloaded successfully'));
            } else {
                drupal_set_message(t('there was error'));
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Edited

Comment: You are using `@` to suppress errors, so it's no wonder you're not seeing any. Remove the `@`s

Comment: What is $currPath set to? what is $local_File set to?

oh and in one place you use $sourcefile in the other you use $remote_file .. whats in there too?

Comment: Sorry i was testing, I edited my source

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, remove the "@" from your function calls.
2. Second, make sure that your error reporting is set to E_ALL.

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
3. Examine the browser output, and the web server error logs.

That should help you troubleshoot.